# carousel not responive on small screens (CSS HTML Js ) No framwork needed

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, carousel

I have an issue with carousel imges slider

the problem appear on the small screens I used trnasform tranlate x to make the slider change the imges with Js

the problem is on the small screens the imges start to confilct and not appearing in the approprate way.

her is the link for the project in live [Project](https://brand-banner.vercel.app/)

HTML Code

```
 <section class="slider1">
        <div id="slider" class="container">
            <div class="projects">
                <div class="title">
                    <h5 dir="rtl " lang="ar ">مشاريعنا وتصميماتنا</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel ">
                    <div id="images" class="image-container">
                        <img src="./assets/food.jpg " alt=" تصميم فيسبوك مطعم كابوريا" />
                        <img src="./assets/ozi4.jpg " alt="تصميم اعلان لمحلات كشري الهادي بالفيوم " />
                        <img src="./assets/green.jpg " alt="تصميم اعلان سوشيال ميديا فندق جرين هاوس بني سويف  " />
                        <img src="./assets/ozi.jpg " alt=" تصميم ترويجي لوجبه طعام مطعم اوزي الفيوم" />
                        <img src="./assets/ozi2.jpg " alt=" تصميم بوست سوشيال ميديا تجاري" />
                        <img src="./assets/ozi3.jpg " alt=" تصميم بوست شويال ميديا لحمله اعلان مموله" />
                        <img src="./assets/socialshre.jpg " alt="براند بانر لوجو" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="buttons-container">
                        <button id="left" class="btn ">Prev</button>
                        <button id="right" class="btn">Next</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </section>
```

```
/*Projects Carousal Start*/

.projects {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.3rem;
}

.projects h5 {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    background-image: linear-gradient( to left, var(--brand_color_one--), var(--brand_color_two--), var(--brand_color_three--), var(--brand_color_four--), var(--brand_color_five--));
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    color: transparent;
    padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.carousel {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    height: 530px;
    width: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.image-container {
    display: flex;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.image-container img {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.buttons-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.btn {
    background-color: var(--brand_color_one--);
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 49.5%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 400;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
    height: 2rem;
}

.btn:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
    background-image: linear-gradient( to right, var(--brand_color_one--), var(--brand_color_two--), var(--brand_color_three--), var(--brand_color_four--), var(--brand_color_five--));
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    color: transparent;
}

.btn:focus {
    outline: none;
}


/*Projects Carousal End*/
```

```
const images = document.getElementById("images");
const leftBtn = document.getElementById("left");
const rightBtn = document.getElementById("right");
const img = document.querySelectorAll("#images img");

//iniate index
let idx = 0;
//func interval to automate slides moving
let interval = setInterval(run, 2000);

//func changeImage work by checking if the idx bigger
// ..or less than the images array from the dom
function changeImage() {
  if (idx > img.length - 1) {
    idx = 0;
  } else if (idx < 0) {
    idx = img.length - 1;
  }
  images.style.transform = `translateX(${-idx * 500}px)`;
}

//func run increment the indx, call changeImage func
function run() {
  idx++;
  changeImage();
}

//to avoid issues with auto sliding
function resetInterval() {
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = setInterval(run, 2000);
}

rightBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  idx++;
  changeImage();
  resetInterval();
});

leftBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  idx--;
  changeImage();
  resetInterval();
});
// images Silder end
```

Comment: you are setting your images to be 500px wide which is too wide to fit on smaller screens. As they are in a dispaly flex, so you could add `flex-shrink:1` to the images to allow them to shrink if needed. Your javascript also assumes you images will also be 500px wide, calculate this on page load rather than setting it as a hard coded value.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Could this getBoundingClientRect().width help to make it dynamic in the Js

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue now it is responsive on all devices

changed height to auto
changed the width of the image to be dynamic regarding the screen width
using the following :

```
carousel.getBoundingClientRect().width
```

replaced the static code with translating fixed pixels to dynamic

```
function control() {

if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 562px)").matches) {

    for (var i = 1; i < img.length; i++) {

        img[i].classList.add(".img-sm");
        img[i].setAttribute("id", "box");
        img[i].style.width = `${carousel.getBoundingClientRect().width}px`;
    }

    function changeImage() {
        if (idx > img.length - 1) {
            idx = 0;
        } else if (idx < 0) {
            idx = img.length - 1;
        }
        images.style.transform = `translateX(${
          -idx * carousel.getBoundingClientRect().width
        }px)`;
    }
    changeImage();
} else {
    for (var i = 1; i < img.length; i++) {
        img[i].classList.remove(".img-sm");
        img[i].removeAttribute('id');
        img[i].style.width = `${carousel.getBoundingClientRect().width}px`

    }

    function changeImage() {
        if (idx > img.length - 1) {
            idx = 0;
        } else if (idx < 0) {
            idx = img.length - 1;
        }
        images.style.transform = `translateX(${
          -idx * carousel.getBoundingClientRect().width
        }px)`;
    }
    changeImage()
}
```

}

also changed the image element size to be :

```
.image-container img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
object-fit: cover;
flex-shrink: 1;
```

}